# How to characterize matrices such that $Ax\cdot x=0$ for any $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, matrix-equations

As written in the title: what are the properties of matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ such that $Ax\cdot x=0 $ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$? In particular, as special case, assume that $A=M^{-1}P$, where $P$ is any symmetric matrix and $M$ is given. What can be said about the matrices $M$ satisfying that relation?

Comment: $A$ is skew symmetric.

Comment: This is clearly sufficient, but also necessary?

Comment: necessary and sufficient.

Comment: It's necessary, because if $A$ has this property, so does $B = A + A^{\mathsf{T}}$, which is symmetric. For $B$, this means that all eigenvalues of $B$ are $0$ (or else $Bx\cdot x$ would be nonzero for an eigenvector) so $B=0$ since symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: You have the form $x^T A x$ with column vector $x.$ First take $x$ with a $1$ in position $i$ and otherwise all $0.$ Calculate and set to zero. Next, for the off diagonal entries, let $x$ have and entry $u$ in position $i,$ then $v$ in position $j,$ all others $0.$ Calculate and set to zero, for all possible real pairs $u,v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_i$ refer to the column vector with a $1$ in position $i$ and all other components equal to $0.$

First, let $x = e_i.$ Then $0 =x^T A x = A_{ii}.$ That is, all diagonal elements of $A$ are required to be $0.$

Second, with $i \neq j$ let $x = e_i + e_j.$ Since we already know that all $A_{kk} = 0,$ we calculate that $0 =x^T A x = A_{ij} + A_{ji}.$ That is, $A$ is skew symmetric.

It should help to do these calculations by hand with a sample 3 by 3 matrix, say
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
o&p&q \\
r&s&t \\
u&v&w \\
\end{array}
\right)  
$$